# Input/output Java example

Tags: java, input, collections, java.util.scanner

I am trying to create a program that repeatedly asks for the water level which should be rising continuously, and **my program should detect when there have been three decreasing readings in a row**. Here is what is printed on the console:

*What is the water level at now (in mm): 20

What is the water level at now (in mm): 21

What is the water level at now (in mm): 23

What is the water level at now (in mm): 25

What is the water level at now (in mm): 27

What is the water level at now (in mm): 27

What is the water level at now (in mm): 34

What is the water level at now (in mm): 22

What is the water level at now (in mm): 25

What is the water level at now (in mm): 26

What is the water level at now (in mm): 28

What is the water level at now (in mm): 27

What is the water level at now (in mm): 26

What is the water level at now (in mm): 25

It appears that the flood is subsiding.*

Currently, I know I should loop it but I've been working with python so I am unsure how to proceed with java. **How can I store the input of the question in order to compare it with he previous answer?** Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class waterLevelProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double waterLevel, initialWaterLevel;
        waterLevel = 0;
        System.out.print("What is the water level at now (in mm): ");
        initialWaterLevel = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();

        while (waterLevel > 0){
            System.out.println("What is the water level at now (in mm): ");
            waterLevel = new Scanner(System.in).nextDouble();
            if (waterLevel > initialWaterLevel){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -and if you don't need to store all of the readings, just store a few at a time in a queue.

Comment: Share with us how you'd do it in Python, and if there's a specific bit you're having trouble translating to Java, we can help with that.

Comment: @Joe C if you are well aware of translating java to python kindly translate the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are comparing current `waaterLevel` with first waterLevel i.e `initialWaterLevel` each time, so you are getting unexpected output. You should update you `initialWaterLevel` to current level at the end of loop so that you can compare from it in next loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    double waterLevel, initialWaterLeve;
    waterLevel = 0;
    initialWaterLeve = 0;
    int count=0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (waterLevel > 0){
        System.out.println("What is the water level at now (in mm): ");
        waterLevel = sc.nextDouble();
        if (waterLevel < initialWaterLevel){
              count++;
        }
        else{
              count=0;
        }

        if(count>=3){
            System.out.println("It appears that the flood is subsiding.");
            break; // if you want to come out of loop.
        }
        initialWaterLevel = waterLevel;
    }
}
```

There is no need of ArrayList or Queue because your objective is to check whether three decrease in a row happens or not which can easily be done by `int` variable. (Remember such tricks)

Comment: Why are you creating a new Scanner every iteration?

Comment: Thanks! Had to change the count to 4 but other than that, that's what I was missing! I forgot count!

Answer (score 0):

A simple example on how to store values in your program using an ArrayList:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class waterLevelProgram {

    ArrayList<double> waterLevels = new ArrayList<double>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (true){
            System.out.println("What is the water level at now (in mm): ");
            currentWaterLevel = scanner.nextDouble();
            waterLevels.add(currentWaterLevel);
            if (isFloodSubsiding())
                System.out.println("Flood is subsiding");
        }
    }

    public static boolean isFloodSubsiding(){
        if (waterLevels.size() >= 3)
        {
            return 
            (
           waterLevels.get(waterLevels.size()-1) < waterLevels.get(waterLevels.size()-2) 
        && waterLevels.get(waterLevels.size()-2) < waterLevels.get(waterLevels.size()-3)
            );
        }
        else 
            return false;
    }
}
```

But as stated by @jack you don't really need storing if you have to handle only an alert when the waterLevel is decreasing three times in a row.
If you need more complex operations (statistical report for example) this could be a tip on how to work with ArrayList.

Comment: i think if condition never works, as the last element in `waterLevels` would be `currentWaterLevel`.

Comment: solved, but to me the question was about how to store data